# Animate the drawing of a line in Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, animation, pixi.js

Is it possible to animate the drawing of a line in Pixi.js? (Canvas, WebGL, whatever.)

I completely understand how to animate an already-rendered line or object, but how do you make it animate the *drawing of the line itself*, as if with TweenMax? I've searched exhaustively through examples and code, and I'm shocked that I have been unable to find a single point of reference for doing this.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/majpfx8q/)

```
var stage = new PIXI.Container();
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();

graphics.lineStyle(20, 0x33FF00);
graphics.moveTo(30,30);
graphics.lineTo(600, 300);

stage.addChild(graphics);

animate();

function animate() {
    renderer.render(stage);
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do the animation yourself - draw it short first, and then make it longer and longer.

For example, here I added a variable "p" (for percentage), that goes from 0 (not drawn at all) to 1 (fully drawn). In your rendering loop, you'd increase p, until it gets to 1.

```
var p = 0; // Percentage

function animate() {
    if (p < 1.00)  // while we didn't fully draw the line
        p += 0.01; // increase the "progress" of the animation

    graphics.clear();
    graphics.lineStyle(20, 0x33FF00);
    graphics.moveTo(30,30);
    // This is the length of the line. For the x-position, that's 600-30 pixels - so your line was 570 pixels long.
    // Multiply that by p, making it longer and longer. Finally, it's offset by the 30 pixels from your moveTo above. So, when p is 0, the line moves to 30 (not drawn at all), and when p is 1, the line moves to 600 (where it was for you). For y, it's the same, but with your y values.
    graphics.lineTo(30 + (600 - 30)*p, 30 + (300 - 30)*p);


    renderer.render(stage);
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
```